# Array Length not Increasing with .push()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

This question refers to the code below. I have a variable array to which I push elements called person_list. My expectation is that as I push elements to person_list (by pressing the add button), the size of the array should increase. However this is not the case. Whenever I press the add button, the current value in the input box overwrites the first element of the array and the array size is not incremented. What am I doing wrong?

```
$(function() {
  window.person_list = [];
  btns_event_listener();
});

function btns_event_listener() {
  $("#add_btn").click(function() {
    person_list.push($("#_IWID_Persons_field").val());
    alert(person_list.length);
  }); 
}
```

Here is the related HTML:

```
<tr id="_IWID_Persons_Config">
    <td width="20%" class="lotusFormLabel lotusFormFieldRow lotusNowrap"><label for="name"> Include Persons: </label></td>
    <td class="lotusFormFieldRow">
        <input type="text" value="" class="lotusText" id="_IWID_Persons_field">
        <button id="add_btn">Add</button>
    </td>
    <td width="40%" class="lotusFormFieldRow"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Whaat is `_IWID_Persons_field `?

Comment: It should be "#_IWID_Persons_field". I fixed it.

Comment: What is `$("#_IWID_Persons_field")`? are you sure .val on it isn't returning null or undefined for some reason?

Comment: It would be nice to have a piece of code of your HTML

Comment: @Kevin i don't think null or undefined would replace the elements in the array. Do you? Looks to me like the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code? Something else might be interacting.

Comment: check the link http://jsfiddle.net/Y3bXQ/ its working properly

Comment: @VedaSadhak Your code looks fine to me..Can you please create a jsfiddle and explain your porblem

Comment: Ill post the related HTML. By the way this file uses Dojo aswell, would that cause a problem?

Comment: I just created [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LrQu6/) that matches your code and it works fine. What does your HTML look like for the input field and the button?

Comment: @Veda Sadhak , have you checked the fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/Y3bXQ/

Comment: @VedaSadhak Is that id unique? or does every row have one.

Comment: [Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zLS25/3/), it's working (your code).

Comment: @Kevin if he pushed nothing the length would not increase. Any value, including undefined will increase the length when pushed. `var a = []; a.push(undefined); console.log(a.length); // 1`

Comment: The problem fixed when I changed <button id="add_btn">Add</button> to <button type="button" id="add_btn" value="click">Add</button>

Comment: @VedaSadhak That's strange; [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LrQu6/1/) works as is.

Comment: if you only write  person_list.push(); then it happens otherwise working properly . you can see http://jsfiddle.net/Y3bXQ/1/

Comment: This situation is just like this... http://www.google.ca/imgres?imgurl=http://ninjahumor.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/My-code-doesnt-work-I-have-no-idea-why-My-code-works-I-have-no-idea-why.jpg&imgrefurl=http://ninjahumor.com/my-code-doesnt-work-i-have-no-idea-why/&h=960&w=640&sz=147&tbnid=g0jaMP-xB_agPM:&tbnh=90&tbnw=60&zoom=1&usg=__AtqRfHdi1Mrx4St14mIwlHgAxMU=&docid=StPmxG35_Bg89M&sa=X&ei=HDx9UoSuCYmnsQSVnYDoBA&ved=0CC0Q9QEwAA

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to store `person_list` as a `var` and within the scope of your 'btns_event_listener' function.

**Example**

`var person_list = []`

I have created a [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/UqE98/) with a recommendation.

Comment: What if I want to use this array outside of the function however?

Comment: This doesn't explain why the OP's code doesn't work as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this code.

```
 $(function() {
        var person_list = [];
        btns_event_listener(person_list);
    });

    function btns_event_listener(person_list) {
    
       
        $("#add_btn").click(function() {
            person_list.push($("#_IWID_Persons_field").val());
            
            alert(person_list.length);
            return false;
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the Spread operator (...array_name) instead of the push method.

suppose you have an array such as

```
var array = ["a","b","c"]
```

updates its value by using this trick for adding value at the end of an array

```
array = [...array,"new_value"]
```

or this one for adding value at the starting of the array

```
array = ["new_value",...array]
```

It will work perfectly.